# Use Over-grid Button to reference button's anchor cell in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to use a button's anchor cell in the function that that button calls. My buttons are inserted on different rows. Clicking on one should have it interact only with the data on the row of its anchor cell.

This is for use in a Sheets/Apps Script that I use to search our G Suite domain's Google Groups for external mailing addresses. It is easy to do a memberOf() check for internal users, but G Suite has no way of searching for external users' group memberships.

The script creates a "Remove" button next to each result. Clicking the remove button should remove the user from the group listed
The removal script is working as long as the correct cell is provided. I just can't see how to make sure the button's anchor cell becomes the selected/active cell when the user interacts with it.

Here's the script for adding the remove buttons, to give you an idea of how they're inserted:

```
function createRemoveButtons(numberOfResults) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchResultStartingColumn = 3;
  var searchResultStartingRow = 4;
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfResults.length; i++) {
    const resultRow = numberOfResults[i];
    sheet.getRange(searchResultStartingRow + i, searchResultStartingColumn)
      .activate();
    // Get Remove button image.
    var ImageBlob = DriveApp.getFileById("1wxSNDJhRz5ehxNZBFCoshMW8j2nFTfGx")
      .getBlob().getAs('image/png');
    var image = sheet.insertImage(ImageBlob, searchResultStartingColumn, searchResultStartingRow, 1, 1);
    image.setHeight(29).setWidth(73).assignScript("removeUserFromGroup");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a function for each button and use that function to set the row to act on when that button is clicked.

```
function buttonRow10(){
  var row = 10;
  // Do the things to do on row 10
}
```

The above because the function called by clicking on a button isn't aware of which button was clicked. In other words, contrary as occurs on simple/installable triggers that have an event object as argument, the functions assigned to a button hasn't it.

Comment: Appreciate your help. This is indeed the best way (unfortunately) to use the buttons. In the end, I opted for a solution using dropdown menus/data validation that was less manual and clunky.